# Вывести в console.log верный ответ, используя замыкания

Tags: javascript

Изучаю замыкания, пока что не могу понять как вывести верное значение. В моем примере я добавил newText в console.log(text, newText), ожидая что консоль выведет 'Привет, Андрей' и т.д вместе, но выводит по отдельности. Подскажите куда как правильно в данном примере использовать параметры, чтобы консоль вывела правильный результат.

```js
function makeConsoleMessage(text) {
  function consoleMessage(newText) {
    console.log(text, newText);
  }

  return consoleMessage;
}

const consoleHello = makeConsoleMessage('Привет, ');
const consoleGoodBye = makeConsoleMessage('Пока, ');
const consoleHemingway = makeConsoleMessage('Прощай, ')

consoleHello('Андрей'); // "Привет, Андрей"
consoleGoodBye('Ирина'); // "Пока, Ирина"
```

Comment: Нажимаю здесь кнопку «Выполнить код» — вижу здесь почти идеальный результат. Чем он не устраивает, что значит «по отдельности» и какой должен быть «правильный»?

Comment: Это тренажер, я тоже думал, что ответ должен быть правильным, но в итоге консоль выводит отдельно "Привет," и отдельно "Андрей", а должно выводиться вместе

Comment: Какая консоль? Я проверил chrome, firefox, nodejs — везде выводится вместе. Не могу повторить вашу проблему

Comment: Задача решена, спасибо. Нужно было использовать шаблонные строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть так лучше?

```js
function makeConsoleMessage(text) {
  function consoleMessage(newText) {
    console.log(`${text}, ${newText}`);
  }

  return consoleMessage;
}

const consoleHello = makeConsoleMessage('Привет');
const consoleGoodBye = makeConsoleMessage('Пока');
const consoleHemingway = makeConsoleMessage('Прощай')

consoleHello('Андрей'); // "Привет, Андрей"
consoleGoodBye('Ирина'); // "Пока, Ирина"
```